# Java 8 and lambda calculus equivalent

Tags: java, function, java-8, lambda-calculus

Does anybody have any idea on how to write the basic expressions of (untyped) lambda calculus in java? i.e.

- identity (λx.x),
- self application (λx.x x) and
- function application (λx.λarg.x arg)

Java is not untyped, so I guess any solution will have to accomodate types. 
But I only found the following, cumbersume to read, solutions:

```
static<T> Function<T,T> identity() {
    return x->x;
}

static<T> Function<? extends Function<? super Function,T>,T> self() {
    return x->x.apply(x);
}

static <B,C> Function<? extends Function<B,C>, Function<B,C>> apply() {
   return x -> arg -> x.apply(arg);
}
```

and I am not even sure they are correct(!). Can anybody propose a better alternative?

---

Edit: Note, that I am trying to apply the basic notions of lambda calculus with as little as possible of syntactic sugar or ready-made functions. E.g. I know there is identity(), BiFunction etc. I am trying to implement the above with only the basic lambda constructs available, and that means basically only function application

Comment: if you could explain what `self application` and `function application` are? like an example?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was common knowledge. My mistake. Function application
takes a function and a value as argument and applies the function to the argument.  Self-application is the application of a term to (a copy of) itself. They are more or less the basic buliding blocks, together with identity, for lambda-calculus

Comment: Maybe you should use `compose` method.

Comment: not entirely sure, but the second is something like this? `static <X, Y> Y fAppl(Function<X, Y> f, X x) {
        return f.apply(x);
    }`

Comment: why do you think they are incorrect?

Comment: I am not saying they are incorrect, but given that their signatures are not easy to ready one cannot immediatelly verify that they are correct without having access to a compiler, writing a couple of tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solutions for identity and application are correct. If wouldn't define them as functions however, I find `x->x` and `Function::apply` as readable as `identity()` and `apply()`, so I would simply use them directly.

As for self-application, well, as you note Java is typed, and also in typed lambda calculus self-application is impossible (at least in all typed lambda calculi I know). You can produce something by using raw types (like you did), but then you essentially throw away the part of the type system.

But also, why do you need all this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no actual need for this, just a mental exercise for me, to see how much one can transfer from lambda calculus to java. I did not like the convoluted java signatures, and I thought that somebody might be able to provide a cleaner solution!

Comment: Well, that is probably one of the reasons why - for the two concepts that are appliccable - the `Function`-interface is defined in a way that allows us to express them as `Function::identity` and `Function::apply`

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is this type(translated from table 19 of [cardelli's type systems paper](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/TypeSystems.pdf)).

```
interface Untyped {
    Untyped call(Untyped x);
}
```

This type cleanly embeds the untyped lambda calculus's terms.

```
static Untyped identity = x -> x;
static Untyped self = x -> x.call(x);
static Untyped apply = f -> x -> f.call(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Java much, but it has included lambda expressions recently. Basic way to implement is to have a functional interface (interface having only one method).

The lambda will then be a type of this interface.

```
    interface Apply
    {
          String ApplyArg(int x);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Apply isEven = (n) -> (n%2) == 0;
       //output true
       System.out.println(isEven.ApplyArg(4));
    }
```

You can use generic type interface to make it more universal.

If you want to send lambda as arguments (thus higher order functions) then your interface method will accept another interface.

```
interface Increment {
    Int myFunction(Int x);
}

public static Int AnotherFunc(Increment test, Int y){
  return test.myFunction(y);
}

public static void main (String args[]) {

   Increment inc = (z) -> z++;
   AnotherFunc(inc, 1); //output 2

}
```